# Can I override the mxml request in an HTTPService? How?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, httpservice

I have an HTTPRequest in mxml that has an mx:request defined inside it. I use the info in the mxml request 99% of the time (I thought it was 100% until I found this bug). So I need to send the HTTPRequest with one of the items in the request different. I tried using the send() method and sending my own object, much like you would if no request was defined in the mxml, but it doesn't seem to override it.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this without re-writing every call to send this httpRequest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is probably to remove the mx:request from the HTTPService and pass the parameters in send().  An alternative is to just create another HTTPService that doesn't set the mx:request parameter.

Comment: Thanks James, Kind of figured that was the only answer, but I was hoping for a nice easy way to override it. Oh well.